# AttributeError at / 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip', why and how? stuck here for a while

Tags: python, django

why am I getting this error? something wrong with my media? or with views? below is Media I;m using goose extractor to try to extract the image from the user posted url, maybe I did something wrong there I simply followed here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

media.py

```
import json
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
from goose import Goose

def get_content(url):

    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.Request.urlopen(req).read()
    return response 


def extract(url):
    url = get_content(url)
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return json.dumps(resposne)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        url = request.GET.get('url')
        image = extract(url)
        try:
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
        except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

        if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                thread_list = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
        else:
                thread_list = Post.objects.all()
                thread_list = sorted(thread_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

        paginator = Paginator(thread_list, 30)

        try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
                "categories":categories,
                "image":image
        }
        return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

This `AttributeError` is the error you'll get if `url` is `None`. You should have better handling of this, since it is an external parameter: either have a default value that will work, or tell the user directly that a url is required.

I suspect this is because the request never specified the `url` parameter. If your original request was the following, I think this part would work (but, I'm not experienced with Django):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?url=something
```

I also noticed in this line:

```
sort = request.GET["sort"].strip # should be:
sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
```

Because I'm assuming you want to get the `strip`ped string, not the `strip` method of the string. (this is not related to the original error you posted about, it is coincidental that `strip` is involved in both)

Comment: Yes thanks, my mistake for the strip. I had a feeling url being none will give the error, but on my website user can post picture and url. (both of them are blank and null = True)....for the user posted picture, that image can be used. ....so error is coming from media.py get_content method? url being not parametrized right?